# Parse HTML table columns with bash

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, html-parsing, xmllint

I'm trying to extract 3 columns from a table in HTML. I need hostname, product + region and date added. So they would be columns 1, 3, 4.

```
<div class="table sectionedit2">
  <table class="inline">
    <tr class="row0">
      <th class="col0 centeralign">hostname</th>
      <th class="col1 centeralign">AKA (Client hostname)</th>
      <th class="col2 leftalign">Product + Region</th>
      <th class="col3 centeralign">date added</th>
      <th class="col4 centeralign">  decom. date  </th>
      <th class="col5 centeralign">           builder           </th>
      <th class="col6 centeralign">  build cross-checker  </th>
      <th class="col7 leftalign"> <strong>decommissioner</strong></th>
      <th class="col8 centeralign">customer managed filesystems</th>
      <th class="col9 centeralign">  only company has root?  </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row1">
      <th class="col0 centeralign">HostName01</th>
      <td class="col1 leftalign">Host01</td>
      <td class="col2 leftalign">EU</td>
      <td class="col3 centeralign">2007-01-01</td>
      <td class="col4 leftalign"></td>
      <td class="col5 centeralign">Me</td>
      <td class="col6 centeralign">You</td>
      <td class="col7 leftalign">Builder01</td>
      <td class="col8 leftalign">xChecker01</td>
      <td class="col9 centeralign">yes</td>
    </tr>
   <tr class="row2">
     <th class="col0 centeralign">HostName02</th>
     <td class="col1 leftalign">Host02</td>
     <td class="col2 leftalign">U.S</td>
     <td class="col3 centeralign">2008-09-29</td>
     <td class="col4 leftalign"></td>
     <td class="col5 leftalign">Me01</td>
     <td class="col6 leftalign">You01</td>
     <td class="col7 leftalign">Builder02</td>
     <td class="col8 leftalign">xChecker02</td>
     <td class="col9 centeralign">yes</td>
```

I want to get:

```
Hostname     Product + Region   Date added

HostName01   EU                 2007-01-01

HostName02   U.S                2008-09-29
```

Previously I tried stripping the HTML tags and using awk, although some of the columns in the table are empty. This means I didn't get colums 1, 3 and 4 for all the rows.

I am trying to use:

```
xmllint --html --shell --format table.log <<< "cat //table/tr/th/td[1]/text()"
```

This is giving me the second column, I tried "[0]" which doesn't work and I'm not sure how to get multiple columns at once.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

- run `xmllint --xpath` with an XPath expression that uses `position()=` to grab just columns 1, 3, and 4: `//table/tr/*[position()=1 or position()=3 or position()=4]`
- pipe through `perl -pe "s/<th class=\"col0/\n<th class=\"col0/g"`, etc., to strip out the markup and break it up into separate lines
- pipe through `grep -v '^\s*$'` to strip out blank lines
- pipe through `column -t` at the end to pretty-print it

Like this:

```sh
xmllint --html \
  --xpath "//table/tr/*[position()=1 or position()=3 or position()=4]" \
    table.log \
    | perl -pe "s/<th class=\"col0/\n<th class=\"col0/g" \
    | perl -pe 's/<tr[^>]+>//' \
    | perl -pe 's/<\/tr>//' \
    | perl -pe 's/<t[dh][^>]*>//' \
    | perl -pe 's/<\/t[dh]><t[dh][^>]*>/|/g' \
    | perl -pe 's/<\/t[dh]>//' \
    | grep -v '^\s*$' \
    | column -t -s '|'
```

The above assumes the HTML document is in the file `table.log` (which seems like an odd name for an HTML file, but it appears to be the name that’s used in the question…). If the document is actually in some other `*.html` file, of course just put the actual filename.

That will give you output like this:

```
hostname    Product + Region  date added
HostName01  EU                2007-01-01
HostName02  U.S               2008-09-29
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your html is well-formed xml, [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) can do it:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//table/tr' -v '*[contains(@class,"col0")]' -o $'\t' \
                                  -v '*[contains(@class,"col2")]' -o $'\t' \
                                  -v '*[contains(@class,"col3")]' -n       \
    file.html
```

```
hostname    Product + Region    date added
HostName01  EU  2007-01-01
HostName02  U.S 2008-09-29
```